# Hyperledger Fabric - Unable to retrieve transientMap on peer during Invocation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a question regarding the transient map. I am trying to invoke a transaction with a transientMap in the request but on the peer itself the map arrives empty. Is there some missing implementation or am I doing something wrong? This is how I'm passing the options on the request:

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("ENCKEY", "MYENCKEY");
var request = {
    chaincodeId: 'parts',
    fcn: 'create',
     args: ['sn234'],
    transientMap: myMap,
    chainId: 'mychannel',
    txId: tx_id
};
return channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);
```

And then in the chaincode I'm reading the map simply with:
`APIstub.GetTransient()` but I get an empty map. The transaction is otherwise completed fine without issues.

I'm working with 1.1.0-alpha version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I only needed to change how I create the map in the first place, from `transientMap: myMap` to `transientMap: { 'key': 'value' }`